# Как убрать обводку желтым тега инпут в хроме?

Tags: javascript, css

Как убрать обводку желтым тега инпут в хроме?

Answer (score 3):

```
<style>
    input { outline:none; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Еще можете почитать полезную статью про [textarea и input](http://shublog.ru/ajax/jquery/9-khitrostejj-html-tega-textarea/), там описано также как бороться с ресайзом текстареи в хроме и со скроллами в ие и др. полезные вещи